# fdesetup authrestart fail with error

Tags: macos

I have a FileVault On M1 chip mac book air.

```
macOS Monterey 
Version 12.2
MacBook Air (M1, 2020)
Chip Apple M1
```

To remotely restart a FileVault On Mac, I always use the following command:

```
sudo fdesetup authrestart -user $(whoami) -inputplist < ~/login.plist
```

But I got following error

```
Error: Unable to restart (error = 45).
```

the same as:

```
sudo fdesetup authrestart -user $(whoami)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar command

```
sudo fdesetup authrestart
```

This command works on my Intel-MAC. Using it on a M1 MAC it get the error:

```
File vault is off
```

Never-the-less is activated. So it seems to be a special problem with M1 MACs